# Runtime Error when edit user's profile data in Android

Tags: android, android-contacts

I want my app to modify user's profile contact information in Android. However, it keeps showing Runtime Error, which is NullPointerException.

```
private void updateUserProfile(Uri uri, Profile profile) {
    String mRawContactId = null;
    Cursor mContactCursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
    if (mContactCursor.moveToFirst()) {
        String mContactId = getCursorString(mContactCursor, 
                ContactsContract.Contacts._ID);

        Cursor mRawContactCursor = getContentResolver().query(
                RawContacts.CONTENT_URI, 
                null, 
                Data.CONTACT_ID + " = ?",
                new String[] {mContactId}, 
                null);

        Log.v("RawContact", "Got RawContact Cursor");

        try {
            ArrayList<String> mRawContactIds = new ArrayList<String>();
            while(mRawContactCursor.moveToNext()) {
                String rawId = getCursorString(mRawContactCursor, RawContacts._ID);
                Log.v("RawContact", "ID: " + rawId);
                mRawContactIds.add(rawId);
            }

            for(String rawId : mRawContactIds) {
                // Make sure the "last checked" RawContactId is set locally for use in insert & update.
                mRawContactId = rawId;
            }                           
        } finally {
            mRawContactCursor.close();
        }
    }

    try {
        ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();

        ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(Data.CONTENT_URI)
                .withValue(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, mRawContactId)
                .withValue(Data.MIMETYPE, Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                .withValue(Data.DATA1, profile.getEmail())
                .withValue(Email.TYPE, Email.TYPE_HOME)
                .withValue(Email.DISPLAY_NAME, "Email")
                .build());
        getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (OperationApplicationException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I find it's in the line `getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);`. But none of `getContentResolver()`, `ContactsContact.AUTHORITY` & `ops` can be null.

Can anyone tell me what is the problem? Thanks

Comment: Can you post the error log?

Comment: Oh thanks I just fix it. It seems like I don't need mContactCursor to drag the profile info.